# Magento 1.7.2 problems with order processing

Tags: paypal, magento-1.7, magento

I hope you all can help, I haven't had much luck on the Magento Forums.  My problem relates to a move/upgrade I recently did on my Magento store.

The site on my old server, running 1.7.0 runs with out any problems with orders and Paypal.  Recently though, I moved to a new server and so while I was moving I figured I would upgrade the site.  For whatever reason now (after wrestling with Paypal Advanced Settings), I can get the customer's order paid for, but I can't get the orders invoiced and shipped out of the system.  For obvious reasons this is a big issue.  Is there something I missed in my move or what?  It just gives me the "Unable to save the invoice." error.  It seems this is not a unusual problem, but all those I found dealt with older versions, and on top of that, referred to a log file that I don't seems to have (execptions.log under var/log).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what your issue might be, but you can enable logging under System > Configuration > Developer (it's the bottom tab on the left) >  Log Settings > Enable. Then just make sure the var/log directory is writable by Apache (or your server software of choice).

Comment: Cags,  You helped me out with that.  Logs I can read, and as I suspected, duplicate invoice exists.  Means I missed a table copy when I moved the database over to the new server.  What Table I'm not entirely sure yet. The code reads: ' exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '100000078' for key 'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_INVOICE_INCREMENT_ID'' in X:\site-hosting\ElectricBrewSupply\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:'

Answer (score 4):

For those in the future who experience similar problems:

Magento 1.7.2 with Paypal Advanced I had to do the following when I upgraded from 1.7.0 to 1.7.2 and moved my server.

1. Paypal: disable SSL verification under payment options(this screws up the communication with PayPal.
2. Duplicate invoice problem: (which may also apply to sales order and shipping)
   -->  In database find tables eav_entity_type and eav_entity_store 
   --> Using eav_entity_type, identify the entity_type_store for the entity_model you need (sales/order, sales/order_invoice, sales/order_creditmemo, sales/order_shipment) with this you can then go into entity_type_store and cross entity_type_id with the last increment_last_id.  If your last invoice in the admin section is 100000070, then set the corresponding entity_type_id col, increment_last_id = 100000070.

This worked perfect for me, but I didn't know where to enable logging, thanks Cags for you help there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just what I needed to solve a similar problem!

Comment: Thanks Hatrickwah
Had duplicate after trying to synchronize customers and orders for development to production dbs. using sqlyog and missed out that important entity_type_store for last increment id. nearly gave up. Thanks alot, saved me so much time

Answer (score 0):

This is a known [bug](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/?issue=13071) introduced in Magento CE 1.6 and 1.7. For a solution, go to app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote.php and change:

```
$bind      = array(':increment_id' => (int)$orderIncrementId);
```

to:

```
$bind      = array(':increment_id' => $orderIncrementId);
```

Comment: It is bad practice to edit the Magento core.  This fix has been turned into an extension here: https://github.com/philwinkle/Philwinkle_AlphaIncrement

Answer (score 0):

I found M2e conflict with Fooman:SameOrderInvoiceNumber extension that manipulate invoice numbers

There is required to disable Fooman extension, or modify it code
http://www.masterdef.net/blog/magento-m2e-error-invoice-was-not-created-reason-sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-1062-duplicate-entry-2300011342-for-key-unq_sales_flat_invoice_increment_id/#more-65